# JSHint won't allow forEach in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I keep getting EsLint errors for having `forEach` in my loop. How can I fix the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.m_V.length; ++i) {
                var o = this.m_V[i];
                var node = o.m_Data.GetCurr(this.m_C);
                if (node && node.m_datae.length) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < node.m_datae.length; ++j) 
                        var dataelement = node.m_datae[j].m_dataat
                            AreaId.forEach(function(area) {
                                dataelement.forEach(function(value) {
                                    if (area === value.m_V) {
                                        if (vo.m_p) {
                                            var a = v.m_p.map;
                                        ....
                                         }
                                     }
                                }
                            }, this);
                    }, this);
                }
       }
 }
```

How can I move the forEach out of the code? I tried to move the forEach out but then it didn't know what my variables `node` and 'o' were.

Comment: Usually, when we see nested loops to this degree, it's a sign that the code should be refactored.

Comment: what is the error EsLint is giving you

Comment: Why are you mixing `.forEach()` with `for` loops in the first place? Couldn't they all be `.forEach()`? Regarding your last sentence about `node` and `o`, you already seem to know how to deal with that because you have equivalent code as the first line in each of the plain `for` loops.

Comment: running your code through ESLint (once **many** other problems are fixed) does not issue any errors regarding forEach